# Keep receiving windows exit code -1073741819 when running python program from PyCharm

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, fortran, f2py

I have just started to write some programs in Fortran (having no prior experience up to this point), that I am wrapping with f2py and importing into another Python program using PyCharm as my IDE. Before I continue, I should mention that I am using a virtual environment located in another directory to my Python installation directory (both are included in my system path).

Now, when I go to run the Python program through PyCharm, I receive the message "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)". I know the culprit is the call to my imported function from my Fortran module that I wrapped with f2py, because the program does output something before reaching this function call. I do not receive any other error messages pointing to the location of the problem and the debugger in PyCharm cant isolate the problem either. What is even more strange is that when I run the Python program from the windows command terminal, it does not even display any error code.

I have been looking online extensively, but almost all of the proposed solutions people have come up with for this problem do not seem to work for my case. I am quite puzzled as to why I keep getting this error and would really appreciate some guidance from the more knowledgeable Fortran community members.

I am using windows 10 education version 20H2, PyCharm community edition 2021.2, Python 3.9.5 [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)], Fortran .f90 file extensions, and GCC 11.2 for my Fortran compiler via mingw64. Here is the (updated) Fortran file findoverlap.f90:

```
subroutine findoverlap(c, l, m, overlap)

implicit none
double precision, intent(in) :: c(:, :)
integer, intent(in) :: l(:), m(:, :)
integer :: i, j, k, o, p, q, ov1, ov2, kd1, kd2
double precision :: gam, ctop
double precision, intent(out) :: overlap(size(m, 2)*size(c, 2), size(m, 2)*size(c, 2))

overlap = 0.0D0
ov1 = 0
do i=1, size(l)
    do j=1, int(2*i+1)
        do k=1, size(c, 2)
            ov2 = 0
            do o=1, size(l)
                do p=1, int(2*o+1)
                    do q=1, size(c, 2)
                        kd1 = int((i+o-abs(i-o))/(i+o+abs(i-o)))
                        kd2 = int((p+j-abs(j-p))/(p+j+abs(j-p)))
                        gam = gamma(0.5D0*(l(i)+l(o))+1.5D0)/sqrt(gamma(l(i)+1.5D0)*gamma(l(o)+1.5D0))
                        ctop = (2.0D0*c(i, k))**(0.5D0*l(i)+0.75D0)*(2.0D0*c(o, q))**(0.5D0*l(o)+0.75D0)
                        overlap(ov1, ov2) = kd1*kd2*gam*ctop/(c(i, k)+c(o, q))**(0.5D0*(l(i)+l(o))+1.5D0)
                        ov2 = ov2 + 1
                    end do
                end do
            end do
            ov1 = ov1 + 1
        end do
    end do
end do

end subroutine findoverlap
```

and here is the windows command terminal readout when I wrap this program:

```
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39>python -m numpy.f2py -c -m overlap "C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\Research\findoverlap.f90" --compiler=msvc --fcompiler=gnu95 --f90exec="C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe"
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "overlap" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:> C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9\overlapmodule.c
creating C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9
Reading fortran codes...
        Reading file 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\PycharmProjects\\Research\\findoverlap.f90' (format:free)
Post-processing...
        Block: overlap
                        Block: findoverlap
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
        Building module "overlap"...
                Creating wrapper for Fortran subroutine "findoverlap"("findoverlap")...
                Constructing wrapper function "findoverlap"...
                  overlap = findoverlap(c,l,m)
        Wrote C/API module "overlap" to file "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9\overlapmodule.c"
        Fortran 90 wrappers are saved to "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9\overlap-f2pywrappers2.f90"
  adding 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9\fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9' to include_dirs.
copying C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.c -> C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9
copying C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.h -> C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9
  adding 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9\overlap-f2pywrappers2.f90' to sources.
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe
Found executable C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-11.2.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-checking=release --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,fortran,ada,objc,obj-c++,jit --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts --enable-libstdcxx-time --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev4, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-boot-ldflags='-pipe -Wl,--dynamicbase,--high-entropy-va,--nxcompat,--default-image-base-high -Wl,--disable-dynamicbase -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc' 'LDFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-pipe -Wl,--dynamicbase,--high-entropy-va,--nxcompat,--default-image-base-high' --enable-linker-plugin-flags='LDFLAGS=-static-libstdc++\ -static-libgcc\ -pipe\ -Wl,--dynamicbase,--high-entropy-va,--nxcompat,--default-image-base-high\ -Wl,--stack,12582912'
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.2.0 (Rev4, Built by MSYS2 project)
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
building 'overlap' extension
compiling C sources
creating C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\Users
creating C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\Users\Owner
creating C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\Users\Owner\AppData
creating C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\Users\Owner\AppData\Local
creating C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp
creating C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo
creating C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DNPY_DISABLE_OPTIMIZATION=1 -IC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9 -IC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt /TcC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9\overlapmodule.c /FoC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9\overlapmodule.obj
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DNPY_DISABLE_OPTIMIZATION=1 -IC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9 -IC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt /TcC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9\fortranobject.c /FoC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9\fortranobject.obj
compiling Fortran sources
Fortran f77 compiler: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -O3 -funroll-loops
Fortran f90 compiler: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -O3 -funroll-loops
Fortran fix compiler: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -O3 -funroll-loops
creating C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects
creating C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\Research
compile options: '-IC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9 -IC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -c'
gfortran.exe:f90: C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\Research\findoverlap.f90
gfortran.exe:f90: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9\overlap-f2pywrappers2.f90
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -Wall -g -shared C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\Research\findoverlap.o C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9\overlap-f2pywrappers2.o -LC:\msys64\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\11.2.0 -LC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs -LC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\PCbuild\amd64 -o C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\.libs\libfindover.62RN4VDR4NEOYZPE5JIDOJVOJIB3FGCH.gfortran-win_amd64.dll -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -Wl,--output-def,C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\libfindover.62RN4VDR4NEOYZPE5JIDOJVOJIB3FGCH.gfortran-win_amd64.def -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-import -static -mlong-double-64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\lib.exe /def:C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\libfindover.62RN4VDR4NEOYZPE5JIDOJVOJIB3FGCH.gfortran-win_amd64.def /OUT:C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\libfindover.62RN4VDR4NEOYZPE5JIDOJVOJIB3FGCH.gfortran-win_amd64.lib /MACHINE:X64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\11.2.0 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\ATLMFC\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64 /EXPORT:PyInit_overlap C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9\overlapmodule.obj C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9\fortranobject.obj C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\libfindover.62RN4VDR4NEOYZPE5JIDOJVOJIB3FGCH.gfortran-win_amd64.lib /OUT:.\overlap.cp39-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\src.win-amd64-3.9\overlap.cp39-win_amd64.lib
copying C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo\Release\.libs\libfindover.62RN4VDR4NEOYZPE5JIDOJVOJIB3FGCH.gfortran-win_amd64.dll -> .\overlap\.libs
Removing build directory C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6705kvo
```

Thanks in advance for any help and please let me know if you need any other information.

EDIT: I removed the x and y arrays from my Fortran code and replaced the size(x) or size(y) lines with int(2*i+1), as was suggested to be the problem, but I still receive the same error code.

Comment: You don't allocate `x` or `y` before you assign to them. `x(:)=...` does not allow automatic (re-)allocation and is different from `x=...`.

Comment: @francescalus Thank you for pointing that out! I changed my Fortran code to remove the allocatable arrays, but I still receive the same error code. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you [edit] to show the code with those modifications?

Comment: @francescalus I have added the modifications to the code above.

Comment: The terminal output still seems to refer to the error/warning message with the first code. Do you still have the same output, or something else when building?

Comment: @francescalus Ah sorry about that, I just added the terminal output for the modified code.

Comment: Have you compiled with all runtime checks? At first glance the first time you do `overlap(ov1, ov2)` you do that with `ov1=0` and `ov2=0`, when the lower bounds of `overlap` are 1 (assuming `m` and `c` aren't zero-sized)..

Comment: @francescalus I wrapped my Fortran code with runtime checks and debugging options and it turns out that the do loops corresponding to dimension 2 of 'overlap' were iterating passed the upper bounds I declared for this array. I am sorry to have wasted your time with such a trivial mistake and thank you for all your assistance.